# How to set java.awt.awtpermission in policy file?

Tags: java, swing, awt

My code is like getWaitMessageBox().setAlwaysOnTop(true);.

This throws the

java.security.AccessControlException: access denied (java.awt.AWTPermission setW
indowAlwaysOnTop)
        at java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Window.setAlwaysOnTop(Unknown Source)

So I need to set the awtpermission in my policy file for "setAlwaysOnTop".

How can I add this into my policy file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ["Default Policy Implementation and Policy File Syntax"](http://download.java.net/jdk8/docs/technotes/guides/security/PolicyFiles.html) explains the syntax of policy files.  The syntax is [here](http://download.java.net/jdk8/docs/technotes/guides/security/PolicyFiles.html#FileSyntax).

The ["Permissions in Java™ SE 7 Development Kit (JDK)"](http://download.java.net/jdk8/docs/technotes/guides/security/permissions.html) document lists all of the standard permissions.  The permissions for AWT are listed [here](http://download.java.net/jdk8/docs/technotes/guides/security/permissions.html#AWTPermission).

From these we can deduce that the permission should be set as follows:

```
    permission java.awt.AWTPermission "setWindowsAlwaysOnTop";
```

The permission target is confirmed by the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/AWTPermission.html).

Comment: Is this right? permission java.awt.awtPermission setAlwaysOnTop; I believe the target is wrong. How to set the target for this?

Comment: Thanks a lot.I have added the above line in my newly created file. In eclipse VM arguments I added, -Djava.security.manager -Djava.security.policy=test.policy. File is located in my base directory. But it doesn't have any effect at all? Is my file location correct?

Comment: @Karthik - I don't know.  Try using the absolute pathname for the file.

Comment: @StephenC Those links don't work anymore, do you have updated links?